# Parsing the results of facebook sdk json to get albums images

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift

I have searched the forums and stack overflow for it and still can't understand how to do this. I don't know how to parse the results for a specific album in the results. I want to get the photos for the profile pictures album. So far I got:

```
     func retrieveFBProfileAlbum(){
            print("RetrievingFBProfileAlbum")
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/albums/", parameters: ["fields": "name, photos"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                  //  let results = result as! NSDictionary
                 //   print(result)
                    if let array: AnyObject = result["data"] {


                        for resultDict in array as! [AnyObject] {

                            if let resultDict = resultDict as? [String : AnyObject] {

                                for (name, value) in resultDict{
                                   print("NAME A: \(name), VALUE A \(value)")                           

                                  }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }else{

                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }

                })

        }
```

I got the results as id, name, photos, id, name, photos. Not sure what to do with this :( I can print only the names of the albums but I don't know how to get the pics of Profile Pictures album:/
Please help as Ive spent many hours on this and still can't get it.

Here's the console output for print(Name:

```
    RetrievingFBProfileAlbum
NAME A: id, VALUE A 357463944266729
NAME A: photos, VALUE A {
    data =     (
                {
            "created_time" = "2016-05-04T11:04:02+0000";
            id = 1192004844145964;
            name = "Yess!!:) Our New Baby!:)100% Electric !";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2016-04-29T12:58:29+0000";
            id = 1189130857766696;
            name = "Coming on Wed!!:)";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2016-04-09T16:55:35+0000";
            id = 1176951032318012;
            name = "Celebrating the good times!:)\nSwietujemy dobre czasy!:)";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2016-02-27T10:11:35+0000";
            id = 1144990872180695;
            name = "The card on the tv said: 'TV in working order. Help yourself' lol Found close to Canonbury station on the Pavement lol\nKartka na telewizorze mowi: 'Dzialajacy Telewizor Wez sobie' Znalezione niedaleko Canonbury Station w Londynie lol!";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2016-02-20T21:44:56+0000";
            id = 1141193462560436;
            name = "Amazing gig in this place:)\nWspanialy koncert w tym miejscu:)";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2016-02-20T15:00:47+0000";
            id = 1141030565910059;
            name = "Pretty rainy in Oxford today;)";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2016-02-04T12:26:26+0000";
            id = 1132017403478042;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2016-02-04T12:15:08+0000";
            id = 1132014160145033;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-12-18T21:22:28+0000";
            id = 1105697299443386;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-12-18T21:13:21+0000";
            id = 1105694492777000;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-12-17T16:07:03+0000";
            id = 1105120696167713;
            name = "Oxford Circus! Lol!";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-12-14T10:39:47+0000";
            id = 1103646716315111;
            name = "On the way to see our new house:)\nW drodze do naszego nowego domku:)";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-12-12T16:08:24+0000";
            id = 1102853349727781;
            name = "I wonder what are they queuing for lol";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-12-12T16:08:24+0000";
            id = 1102853346394448;
            name = "I wonder what are they queuing for lol";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-12-05T13:38:44+0000";
            id = 1099659323380517;
            name = "Had a nice recording session today";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-25T08:36:30+0000";
            id = 1095105427169240;
            name = "Morning Charm of London;)";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-24T10:55:52+0000";
            id = 1094653970547719;
            name = "Working on a bigger app project for a client!:)";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-21T19:03:42+0000";
            id = 1093483963998053;
            name = "Marta's Birthday Party!";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-19T12:34:39+0000";
            id = 1092463290766787;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-19T12:07:40+0000";
            id = 1092455410767575;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-13T10:20:02+0000";
            id = 1089819014364548;
            name = "This picture was made by Jeremy Pollard";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-12T22:59:17+0000";
            id = 1089636391049477;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-12T22:59:17+0000";
            id = 1089636377716145;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-12T22:59:17+0000";
            id = 1089636341049482;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-12T22:59:17+0000";
            id = 1089636331049483;
        }
    );
    paging =     {
        cursors =         {
            after = MTA4OTYzNjMzMTA0OTQ4MwZDZD;
            before = MTE5MjAwNDg0NDE0NTk2NAZDZD;
        };
        next = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/357463944266729/photos?access_token=EAARr4VZBUZB1sBAGkjT94xtdTntZBMlYfSGyeGdX7AV8UiejafZB3j3BUtcizUci4H7exNYhK8knZATvJlGqEK8ItBt7nA6avvNQmLp3FdLcxwK5as9kHvy10mmBDdP1m74LbLq07PfZBdZB7ZBYskogHthmjFSMlJ2XjAcWyGKh2fAQ2wgwmKVj59NlxjJMJmLLjFv6PPshfQZDZD&limit=25&after=MTA4OTYzNjMzMTA0OTQ4MwZDZD";
    };
}
NAME A: name, VALUE A Mobile Uploads
NAME A: id, VALUE A 105303352816124
NAME A: photos, VALUE A {
    data =     (
                {
            "created_time" = "2016-03-17T13:03:22+0000";
            id = 1157099090969873;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-18T15:00:58+0000";
            id = 1092093134137136;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-17T16:03:07+0000";
            id = 1091665917513191;
            name = "Working on the app design for our newest productivity app! #productivity #wellbeing  #mindfulness #ios #apps";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-17T08:19:03+0000";
            id = 1091515567528226;
            name = "Morning Pages app coming soon!!";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-10T21:23:09+0000";
            id = 1088809341132182;
            name = "Morning Pages app coming soon!!";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-10T15:23:04+0000";
            id = 1088690757810707;
            name = "Working on the app design for our newest productivity app! #productivity #wellbeing  #mindfulness #ios #apps";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-09T15:22:10+0000";
            id = 1088254854520964;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-09T09:00:22+0000";
            id = 1088140484532401;
            name = "Code Imagination is working on a new app! #ios #morningpages #appdevelopment #appdesign";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-08T19:20:02+0000";
            id = 1087913804555069;
            name = "Morning Ritual will clear your mind. Simple and already forgotten technique of well-being.";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-07T16:03:03+0000";
            id = 1087375167942266;
            name = "My iPhone app is coming soon out! :)";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-06T17:15:14+0000";
            id = 1086951271317989;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-05T18:01:33+0000";
            id = 1086518038027979;
            name = "Morning Ritual will clear your mind. Simple and already forgotten technique of well-being.";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-05T17:15:12+0000";
            id = 1086503548029428;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-04T10:00:43+0000";
            id = 1085954754750974;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-03T18:00:11+0000";
            id = 1085715074774942;
            name = "Code Imagination is working on a therapeutic app! Coming Soon!";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-03T13:10:04+0000";
            id = 1085617851451331;
            name = "Code Imagination is working on a new app! #ios #morningpages #appdevelopment #appdesign";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-11-02T16:03:12+0000";
            id = 1085240851489031;
            name = ":)";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-10-31T13:06:03+0000";
            id = 1084283338251449;
            name = "Morning Pages app coming soon!!";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-10-31T08:19:08+0000";
            id = 1084204508259332;
            name = "Working on the app design for our newest productivity app! #productivity #wellbeing  #mindfulness #ios #apps";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-10-30T09:52:10+0000";
            id = 1083819734964476;
            name = "Working on a new app project!! :)";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-10-22T16:43:44+0000";
            id = 1080595525286897;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-10-22T16:43:44+0000";
            id = 1080595035286946;
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-08-22T05:57:16+0000";
            id = 1050046911675092;
            name = "Dziekuje wszystkim za zyczenia; )\nThx All for the Birthday Wishes :)";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-05-20T10:12:04+0000";
            id = 999296236750160;
            name = "Little Bell in Japanese. Available soon! Meanwhile check the english version here: http://buff.ly/1GoTGIH";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-05-19T14:18:40+0000";
            id = 999010216778762;
            name = "Little bell the Japanese Version available soon;))\nLittle Bell wersja Japonska dostepna wkrotce;)";
        }
    );
    paging =     {
        cursors =         {
            after = OTk5MDEwMjE2Nzc4NzYy;
            before = MTE1NzA5OTA5MDk2OTg3MwZDZD;
        };
        next = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/105303352816124/photos?access_token=EAARr4VZBUZB1sBAGkjT94xtdTntZBMlYfSGyeGdX7AV8UiejafZB3j3BUtcizUci4H7exNYhK8knZATvJlGqEK8ItBt7nA6avvNQmLp3FdLcxwK5as9kHvy10mmBDdP1m74LbLq07PfZBdZB7ZBYskogHthmjFSMlJ2XjAcWyGKh2fAQ2wgwmKVj59NlxjJMJmLLjFv6PPshfQZDZD&limit=25&after=OTk5MDEwMjE2Nzc4NzYy";
    };
}
```

I have pasted just the begining of the results as its quite long. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Don't use <pre> and <code> tags on sO. Intent your code by > 4 spaces and SO formats it as code. I've edited your question.

Comment: The code you posted isn't dealing with JSON, it's dealing with objects that have been deserialized from JSON already.

You need to log the data structures you are getting, figure out the structure of the "object graph", and then map out how to walk the object graph to find what you are looking for.

Without seeing the object graph we can't really help you. Try logging the contents of `result` and add that to your question.

Comment: @akmar1984, For the `created_time`, what formatter you use to get the time from this.